# How can I add date text (Bottom-Right Corner) to image and save

Tags: java, android, date, android-camera

I am very new to Java. I need to add date as bottom-right corner text to captured image by my camera and save it. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Eray, welcome to SO. We are not a coding writing service and questions like "I want to do X please write the code for me" will not be answered. Please show us the effort you tried to solve this problem (eg the code you wrote), describe the errors / problems you are getting, and we will try to help you solve them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class WatermarkImage {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            Date now = new Date();

            File origFile = new File("E:/watermark/test.jpg");
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(origFile.getPath());

            // create BufferedImage object of same width and height as of original image
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
                        icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            // create graphics object and add original image to it
            Graphics graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
            graphics.drawImage(icon.getImage(), 0, 0, null);

            // set font for the watermark text
            graphics.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
            String watermark =  sdfDate.format(now);

            // add the watermark text
            graphics.drawString(watermark, (icon.getIconWidth()*80)/100, (icon.getIconHeight()*90)/100);
            graphics.dispose();

            File newFile = new File("E:/watermark/WatermarkedImage.jpg");
            try {
                  ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", newFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(newFile.getPath() + " created successfully!");

      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

// get today day. and put into ListView which is situated on bottom-right corner //in xml file.

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                            day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

TextView out=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
out.setText(day+"."+month+"."+year);
```

Comment: Can I save this??? I want add text to image and save as file. But thanks for answer...

Comment: into image file import image to bitmap open bitmap like canvas and use code upper.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html
I haven't enough time for write it. maybe at night (write if you will have done)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It's saved lot of effort for me

```
            String d = "18-11-2019";            
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(sourceFile);
            Graphics2D graphics = bi.createGraphics();
            Font font = new Font("ARIAL", Font.PLAIN, 50);
            graphics.setFont(font);
            graphics.drawString(d, 50, 50);
            bi.flush();
            ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", targetFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

for bottom right corner u can do somthinge like this

```
private Bitmap addWaterMark(Bitmap src) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    Bitmap waterMark = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.watermark3x);
    int ww = w-waterMark.getWidth();
    int hh = h-waterMark.getHeight();

    canvas.drawBitmap(waterMark, ww, hh, null);

    return result;
}
```